# compare two select statements in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, shell, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to compare two select statements  in oracle SQL

```
select sum(quantity)
from Table 1
where order_number = XXXX

select sum(quantity)
from Table 2
where order_number = XXXX
```

If the quantities do not match, the application will rollback if they match i need to perform update operation.Can any one help me out how to rollback in shell script and perform update operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use inner select statement to do something like...

```
SELECT (whatever operations you gonna do) FROM dual WHERE (select sum(quantity) from Table 1 where order_number = XXXX) = (select sum(quantity) from Table 2 where order_number = XXXX);
```

Neither than that, you can also use CASE WHEN THEN.

Comment: I need to perform update operation in other tables based on this two select statements comparision

Comment: UPDATE table SET column = value WHERE (select sum(quantity) from Table 1 where order_number = XXXX) = (select sum(quantity) from Table 2 where order_number = XXXX);